# C'est du [adjective] ?

Tags: grammaire, articles

The hot sauce packets at the fast food restaurant called Taco Bell have cute sentences printed on them. On one that I just got, it reads:

> I'M YOUR MAIN SQUEEZE.
>   ENTRE NOUS, C'EST DU SÉRIEUX.

I'm reading "du" as the partitive article, but that means that "sérieux" is a noun. Can "C'est du + [adjective]" ever happen?

On wordreference, the [entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/s%C3%A9rieux) for "sérieux" has many entries for sérieux being an adjective, but only one entry for it being a noun; this makes me wonder if "sérieux" in the sentence on my hot sauce is in fact an adjective.

Questions:

- Is "sérieux" an adjective, or a noun, in "C'est du sérieux"?
- Can "C'est du + [adjective]" ever happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sérieux* is a substantive adjective (*adjectif substantivé*), so technically a noun (e.g. in English: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly".)

There are many other examples of such constructions:

> *C'est du bon* (also *c'est de la bonne*)
>
> *C'est du pareil au même*
>
> *C'est du vrai*
>
> *C'est du propre*
>
> *C'est du rouge*
>
> ...

Comment: note for my future self, and other readers: A "substantive adjective" is an adjective that replaces a noun. e.g. "The **meek** shall inherit the earth". http://people.hsc.edu/drjclassics/Latin/general_info_about_grammar/substantive.shtm

Comment: Can I use this construction with any adjective? eg, "C'est du génial", "C'est du mal", etc? Or is it just certain adjectives that a person just learns as time passes?

Comment: @silph You cannot use this form with all adjectives. You can say "C'est du mal.", since "mal" is a noun ("le mal et le bien"). I need to point out though that I don't think I have ever heard "C'est du mal." before ;).

Comment: Not all adjectives do work well. *C'est du génial* is slightly odd but might work in some contexts. *C'est du mal* doesn't (as an adverb), or more precisely, would work with *mal* being already a noun (*c'est du mal que tu lui fais*)